# Reversing and appending to list

Tags: prolog

I'm having trouble understanding how to reverse and append to a list in prolog.

```
/*reverse list code - CALL=reverse([a,b,c],X,[]).*/
reverse([],Z,Z).
reverse([H|T],Z,Acc) :- reverse(T,Z,[H|Acc]).

/*append code*/
append([],L,L).
append([H|T], L, [H|NewT]) :- append(T,L,NewT).

palindrome(Base,Result) :- append(Base,reverse(Base,Result,[]),Result).
```

I'm new to logic programming so I'm trying to achieve getting a base like [a,b,c] and reversing then appending it so result would be [a,b,c,c,b,a]. How do I represent this in thought and code? For now I'm just trying to get back Result that is a reverse appended list.

Comment: you should introduce temporary variables: `palindrome(Base,Result) :- reverse(Base,R,[]), append(Base,R,Result).`. otoh the rule should be `palindrome(Base,Result) :- reverse(Base,Result).`

Comment: Predicates in Prolog are not functions that have return values, so `append(Base, reverse(Base, Result, []), Result)` doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you're making a classic mistake that a lot of imperative programmers make when trying logic programming. You're nesting calls to predicates as though they return values. They don't return values.

All a predicate does is evaluate to `true` or `false`. If `true` then computation continues or if `false` then the computation back-tracks looking for another solution.

Here what you need to write:

```
palindrome(Base,Result) :- reverse(Base,Reverse,[]), append(Base,Reverse,Result).
```

So only after `reverse` is true can `append` be called, and once `reverse` completes then `Reverse` is unified and then `Result` can be computed.